# Is the set $\{\vec u+i \vec v+j \vec w\}$ is different from $\{i \vec v+j \vec w\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $\vec u$ be a vector in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $\{\vec v, \vec w\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $i,j \in \mathbb Z$ are integers.

My question:

> Is $A=\{i \vec v+j \vec w\}$ a different set than $B=\{\vec u+i \vec v+j \vec w\}$ ?

Since $\{\vec v, \vec w\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^2$, then $\vec u=m \vec v+n \vec w$ for some scalars $m,n$. Then $$B=\{m \vec v+n \vec w+i \vec v +j \vec w\}=\{(m+i)\vec v+(n+j) \vec w\}=A.$$
So the sets $A$ and $B$ are same.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between real numbers and integers.

Comment: The set $A$ is a lattice and $B$ also, but if $m,n$ aren't integers they aren't equal.

Comment: @janmarqz, ohh I see. I was sloppy. I got it. Thanks

Comment: The point is that $\vec u$ may not be expressed as the linear combination of $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ **with integer coefficients**, so the existence of some integer $m$ and $n$ is not generally guaranteed. Your proof is correct **only if** such $m$ and $n$ exist.